# Form_key cookie in magento 2

Tags: magento2, form-key

I see that in magento 2 form_key is set in cookies. Is this cookie present in every page?

Comment: I can say yes. We can find the `form_key` in cookie in every page.

Comment: Well i agree that it appears in pages. But do you what code renders it?

Comment: Should take a look: `vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/FormKey.php`, `vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Observer/RegisterFormKeyFromCookie.php`

Answer (score 3):

I can say yes. We can find the `form_key` in cookie on every page.

vendor/magento/module-page-cache/etc/events.xml

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="register_form_key"
              instance="Magento\PageCache\Observer\RegisterFormKeyFromCookie"
              />
</event>
```

As we can see, for each Action Dispatch request, Magento will try to register the form key from the cookie.

Comment: It works with varnish? It can't cache the page if page sets always the cookie right?